# ffmpeg does not extract all the png files contained inside a mov video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract / convert all the **png** files contained inside a **mov** video file. To do this,I'm using this batch script,that works correctly...

```
pushd %1

if not exist newfiles\ (
mkdir newfiles
)

if not exist newfiles2\ (
mkdir newfiles2
)

:start

for %%F in (*.mov) do (
    md "%%~nF"
    echo "%%~nF"
    ffmpeg -i %%F -r 1 -f image2 -qscale:v 2 "%%~nF\%%~nF_image-%%3d.png"
    copy "%%~nF\%%~nF_image-001.png" ".\newfiles" 
    )
popd
```

**BUT** the problem is that there should be some error on this command :

```
ffmpeg -i %%F -r 1 -f image2 -qscale:v 2 "%%~nF\%%~nF_image-%%3d.png"
        copy "%%~nF\%%~nF_image-001.png" ".\newfiles"
```

because it extracts only **4** images. Instead,I used **virtualdub** to do the same and this time the extracted **png** images are **48**. So,where is the error ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command should be

```
ffmpeg -i %%F -f image2 -vsync 0 "%%~nF\%%~nF_image-%%3d.png"
```

`-r 1` asks ffmpeg to choose 1 frame from each second of the input. `qscale` is not relevant for PNGs. `-vsync 0` is needed to stop ffmpeg from dropping or duplicating frames.